# JavaScript dynamically load script file to create an object and then run .init() on that object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically add a script file that is an IIFE object

```
var DynamicLoadedFile = (function(){
    const id=1;
    const name='Object Name';
    return {
        init: function(){
            console.log('Initialized');
        },
        getInfo: function(){
            return {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name
           }
        }
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

using jQuerys getScript method

```
$.getScript('script url').done(function(script){
    // TODO: Do something with the script if we want
});
```

and I don't know how to get the name of the returned object (in this case DynamicLoadedFile) and then use that to run the 'init' or 'getInfo' functions.

```
i.e. - DynamicLoadedFile.init() or DynamicLoadedFile.getInfo();
```

I can get the name by using substring on the script that is returned

```
var objectName = script.substring(4,script.indexOf('=')).trim();
```

but once I have that I don't know how to use it to call the 'init' or the 'getInfo' methods.

```
i.e. - objectName.init() or objectName.getInfo();
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Or suggestions?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Manual for getScript says, _“The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.”_ - so you can probably not rely on the object already existing at that point.

Comment: Since it's created with `var` and executed (by `getScript`) at global scope, the variable is a property of the `window` object, so `window[objectName].init();` will do it. See some of the answers to the linked question for details.

Comment: @CBroe - **Wow**. I did not know that. The few times I used it (years ago), it had always been executed. Rushman, a `setTimeout(function() { /*...*/ }, 0);` wrapper should deal with that.

Comment: (I would encourage you to find an alternative to doing this, but that's not what you asked. :-) But for what it's worth, you could make the scripts that you're loading this way not create globals, but instead fire a custom event on `window` when they're loaded, with the reference to the object as a property on that event. Your main script listens for the custom event and uses the object when it arrives.)